# How to calculate percentage change using Dataset[]

Tags: dataset, arithmetic

With the following code, I can calculate percentage changes in selected indicators over time. The code is not efficient nor practical to integrate it into `Manipulate` function I already have.

```
pch[x1_, x2_] := Quantity[((x2 - x1)/x1)*100, "Percent"];
jdata[GroupBy["country"], GroupBy["time"], All, {"EVI"}]["Bhutan"] // Normal
jdata[GroupBy["country"], GroupBy["time"], All, {"Exposure index"}]["Bhutan"] // Normal
```

extracts the data for "EVI" and "Exposure index" indicators for Bhutan.

```
<|2012.` -> {<|"EVI" -> 44.19255725212609`|>}, 
  2015.` -> {<|"EVI" -> 40.19403209871271`|>}, 
  2018.` -> {<|"EVI" -> 36.26105903025079`|>}, 
  2021.` -> {<|"EVI" -> 25.73725117803039`|>}|>

<|2012.` -> {<|"Exposure index" -> 42.47413422316401`|>}, 
  2015.` -> {<|"Exposure index" -> 38.87846003288048`|>}, 
  2018.` -> {<|"Exposure index" -> 39.04960632190836`|>}, 
  2021.` -> {<|"Exposure index" -> 
 Missing["KeyAbsent", "Exposure index"]|>}|>
```

I then calculate the percentage change using:

```
(* percentage change in "EVI" in Bhutan *)
x1 = jdata[GroupBy["country"], GroupBy["time"], All, {"EVI"}][
  "Bhutan", First, 1, "EVI"]
x2 = jdata[GroupBy["country"], GroupBy["time"], All, {"EVI"}][
  "Bhutan", Last, 1, "EVI"]
pch[x1, x2]
```

which generates:

```
Quantity[-41.7611, "Percent"]
```

I repeat the same operation for "Exposure index" indicator:

```
 (* percentage change in "Exposure index" in Bhutan *)
 x1 = jdata[GroupBy["country"], GroupBy["time"], 
   All, {"Exposure index"}]["Bhutan", First, 1, "Exposure index"]
 x2 = jdata[GroupBy["country"], GroupBy["time"], All, {"Exposure  index"}]["Bhutan", Last, 1, "Exposure index"]

 pch[x1, x2]
```

This does not work because the last element of the indicator is missing:

```
 2.35437 (-42.4741 + Missing["KeyAbsent", "Exposure index"])
```

My questions/requests:

1. I like to make the percentage change calculations automatically not in the way I illustrated above because I have many indicators to calculate percentage change over time. If possible, calculate the percentage changes for all indicators, not one by one, as I did above.
2. On the way, I encounter a `Missing[Key]` problem because sometimes the first and sometimes the last year's data are missing. In that case, I want to calculate the percentage change over the existing data.
3. My `code` is not efficient and I would like to have a better code to calculate all the percentage changes in all the indicators in the dataset at once.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example dataset similar to the one in OP:

```
data = 
 {<|"country" -> "SriLanka", "time" -> 2010., "indicator" -> "GDP", "data" -> Missing[]|>, 
  <|"country" -> "SriLanka", "time" -> 2011., "indicator" -> "GDP", "data" -> 65292.8|>, 
  <|"country" -> "SriLanka", "time" -> 2012., "indicator" -> "GDP", "data" -> 68434.4|>,
  <|"country" -> "SriLanka", "time" -> 2013., "indicator" -> "GDP", "data" -> 74317.8|>, 
  <|"country" -> "SriLanka", "time" -> 2014., "indicator" -> "GDP", "data" -> Missing[]|>, 
  <|"country" -> "Egypt", "time" -> 2010., "indicator" -> "GDP", "data" -> 218888.3|>, 
  <|"country" -> "Egypt", "time" -> 2011., "indicator" -> "GDP", "data" -> Missing[]|>,
  <|"country" -> "Egypt", "time" -> 2012., "indicator" -> "GDP", "data" -> 279372.8|>, 
  <|"country" -> "Egypt", "time" -> 2013., "indicator" -> "GDP", "data" -> 288586.2|>, 
  <|"country" -> "Egypt", "time" -> 2014., "indicator" -> "GDP", "data" -> 305529.7|>, 
  <|"country" -> "SriLanka", "time" -> 2010., "indicator" -> "Population", "data" -> 20.3|>, 
  <|"country" -> "SriLanka", "time" -> 2011., "indicator" -> "Population", "data" -> 20.4|>,
  <|"country" -> "SriLanka", "time" -> 2012., "indicator" -> "Population", "data" -> 20.5|>,
  <|"country" -> "SriLanka", "time" -> 2013., "indicator" -> "Population", "data" -> 20.7|>,
  <|"country" -> "SriLanka", "time" -> 2014., "indicator" -> "Population", "data" -> Missing[]|>,
  <|"country" -> "Egypt", "time" -> 2010., "indicator" -> "Population", "data" -> 82.8|>,
  <|"country" -> "Egypt", "time" -> 2011., "indicator" -> "Population", "data" -> 84.5|>, 
  <|"country" -> "Egypt", "time" -> 2012., "indicator" -> "Population", "data" -> 86.4|>,
  <|"country" -> "Egypt", "time" -> 2013., "indicator" -> "Population", "data" -> 88.4|>,
  <|"country" -> "Egypt", "time" -> 2014., "indicator" -> "Population", "data" -> 90.4|>};

ds = Dataset @ data
```

[image]

```
percentChange = 100 Differences @ # / # &;
```

A simple query to get a dataset of time series:

```
timeseries = ds[GroupBy["country"], 
  Merge[TimeSeries], 
  <|#indicator -> {DateObject @ Round[{#time}], #data}|> &, 
  MissingBehavior -> None]
```

[image]

If needed we can get a dataset of date paths using the property `"DatePath"`:

```
timeseries[Map[Map[AssociationThread @@ Transpose[#["DatePath"]] &]]]
```

[image]

Or a dataset of `DateListPlot`s:

```
timeseries[Map[Map[DateListPlot]]]
```

[image]

Similarly, we can construct a dataset of percent change time series:

```
pctimeseries = timeseries[Map[KeyMap[# <> " Change" &]] /* 
    Map[Map[#["DatePath"] & @* percentChange]], 
   MissingBehavior -> None]
```

[image]

To process cells involving `Missing[]` we use

```
processMissing = <|#["Year"] -> 
     ReplaceAll[#2, _?(Not@*FreeQ[_Missing]) :> Missing[]]|> &;

pctimeseries = timeseries[Map[KeyMap[# <> " Change" &]] /* 
    Map[Map[Join @@ processMissing @@@ #["DatePath"] & @* percentChange]], 
  MissingBehavior -> None]
```

[image]

```
pctimeseries["SriLanka", "GDP Change", Key@2012]
```

> ```
> 4.59067
> ```

```
Normal @ pctimeseries["Egypt", "GDP Change", Key /@ {2013, 2014}]
```

> ```
> <|2013 -> 3.1926, 2014 -> 5.54561|>
> ```

```
Normal @ pctimeseries["Egypt", {"GDP", "Population"}, Key@2013]
```

> ```
> <|"GDP" -> 3.19256, "Population" -> 2.262443|>
> ```

```
pctimeseries[Map[Map[DateListPlot]]]
```

[image]

```
pctimeseries[DateListPlot[#Egypt, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Egypt ▸ Population Change (%)", 16], 
    ImageSize -> Large] &,
   "Population Change"]
```

[image]

```
pctimeseries[BarChart[#"Egypt", 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Egypt ▸ Population Change (%)", 16], 
    ChartStyle -> 97, ChartLabels -> {2012, 2013, 2014}, 
    "FixedBarSpacing" -> True] &, 
 "Population Change", 
  Key /@ {2012, 2013, 2014}]
```

[image]

etc.

**Note:** We can also use a query on `ds` to get the dataset `pctimeseries`:

```
pctimeseries2 = ds[GroupBy["country"] /* Map[KeyMap[# <> " Change" &]], 
  Merge[TimeSeries /* percentChange /* 
    (processMissing @@@ #["DatePath"] &) /* Apply[Join]],
  <|#indicator -> {DateObject @ Round[{#time}], #data}|> &, 
 MissingBehavior -> None] ;

pctimeseries2 == pctimeseries
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks for a thorough code. I tried to replicate your code with my data set and was successfully getting the exact list of outputs like yours given above. However, at the stage where `pctimeseries = timeseries[...]` I started to get an error message: `Path is expected to be non-empty`. I tried various things but still, have the same error. Why do you think I get this error?

Comment: The error pups up after `timeseries[Map[Map[DateListPlot]]]`.

Comment: a wild guess: probably some  country/indicator combinations are empty in your data.

Comment: Your guess is true. Is there any easy way to overcome this error?

Comment: does `timeseries[Map[Map[DateListPlot]], FailureAction ->"Drop", MissingBehavior -> None]` fix the issue?

Comment: It does not fix the problem because the error comes when I run `pctimeseries = 
 jdataSGI[GroupBy["country"] /* Map[KeyMap[# <> " Change" &]], 
  Merge[TimeSeries /* 
    percentChange /* (#["DatePath"] &)], <|#indicator -> {DateObject@
       Round[{#time}], #data}|> &, MissingBehavior -> None]`. All the codes before this piece works as expected and generates the same results as in your codes above.

Comment: Although my dataset format is exactly the same as your example, I cannot get through this `pctimeseries=jdataSGI[...]`, although I tried `FaliureAction->"Drop"`, `DeleteCases[jdataSGI[...]]` and `DeleteMissing[jdataSGI[...],Missing[]]`. None is solving the problem. With your example dataset above, everything works fine, except `Normal@pctimeseries["Egypt", {"GDP", "Population"}, Key@2013]` which gives failure.

Answer (score 0):

The following `code` (thanks to @Rohi Namjoshi) does what I intend to do but with few caveats:

```
Row[{
  jdata[GroupBy[Key["country"]], All, {"Exposure index", "EVI"}] // 
       Map[Quantity[100.*(Last@# - First@#)/First@#, "Percent"] &], Spacer[10],
  jdata[GroupBy[Key["country"]], Mean, {"Exposure index", "EVI"}]
    }]
```

as you can see from the output table, I am not able to cleanly present the calculations in columns. Indicator names should be column names and the associated calculations should be elements of columns. The first table corresponds to percentage changes and the latter one to mean for each country.

[image]

Also, I could not solve the `Missing[Key]` problem due to missing data for either the initial year or last year.